# 403 Forbidden - Nginx + Passenger - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have installed passenger with nginx but it gives me 403 error. I have tried changing the user of folder multiple times, but it didn't work.

Here is the error:

```
2016/10/22 21:13:26 [error] 31890#0: *1 directory index of "/home/ubuntu/testapp/" is forbidden, client: 45.127.106.26, server: 52.91.45.232, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "52.91.45.232"
2016/10/22 21:13:29 [error] 31890#0: *1 directory index of "/home/ubuntu/testapp/" is forbidden, client: 45.127.106.26, server: 52.91.45.232, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "52.91.45.232"
```

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30;
#    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby;
passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    server { 
     listen 80; 
     server_name 52.91.45.232; 
     passenger_enabled on; 
     root /home/ubuntu/testapp; 
   }
    # server {
      #  listen       80;
       # server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

       # location / {
       #     root   html;
      #      index  index.html index.htm;
     #   }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
    #    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
   #     location = /50x.html {
  #          root   html;
 #       }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
#    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Here is my directory:

```
ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 22 20:45 testapp
```

I'm not able to get this right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add passenger_ruby and passenger_ruby in nginx file. You can look into the file /etc/nginx.conf. you can see passenger_root and passenger_ruby having the ini extension just uncomment it. Or there will be line that looks like include /etc/passenger.conf just uncomment it. I think your problem is with passenger wrapper.